# Facebook App content based on user locale

Tags: php, facebook, locale

I have developed a facebook app which uses 2 languages. French & Dutch. ( Focussed on dutch, dutch speaking belgium and french speaking belgium).

Somehow when I put a test account to french it still displayes it in Dutch.

I have this code for the app

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));


$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
$languageFR = $signed_request["user"]["fr_FR"];

if ($like_status) {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("fans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("fans_dutch.php");
    }
}
else {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("nonfans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("nonfans_dutch.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Who is gonna help me out?

Comment: What does `$signed_request["user"]` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));


$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

if ($like_status) {
    if ($locale == "fr_FR") {  
        include("fans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("fans_dutch.php");
    }
}
else {
    if ($locale == "fr_FR") {  
        include("nonfans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("nonfans_dutch.php");
    }
}

?>
```

There's not `$signed_request["user"]["fr_FR"]` field in the signed request IMHO, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept my answer if it helped you! Cheers!